# How to get the mount point of flash drive by using uuid?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, partition, uuid

I am beginner in ubuntu linux and i need to write simple bash script, that can identify necessary flash drive(which contains only one *vfat* partition) using uuid of this partition, and get the mount point of this flash drive.The ***/etc/fstab*** file does'nt contains mountig rule for this drive.
For example, let partition uuid as  ***7DCD-9380***
Using the readlink tool i can get device link in ***/dev*** catalog :

```
teddy@st1:~$ readlink -f /dev/disk/by-uuid/7DCD-9380  
/dev/sdc1
```

But how i can get  mount point of ***/dev/sdc1*** device ?

Comment: You could mount it wherever you want, for example on `/mnt/flashdrive` (after `mkdir /mnt/flashdrive` of course). What specific mount point are you looking for?

Answer (score 10):

What you're after is `findmnt`. For example:

```
$ findmnt -rn -S UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -o TARGET
/mnt/mountpoint
```

or

```
$ findmnt -rn -S PARTUUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -o TARGET
/mnt/mountpoint
```

If nothing is mounted matching that UUID, nothing is output and the return code is 1 (failure), otherwise, the mountpoint is output and the return code is 0 (success).

### Explanation of options

```
-r, --raw              use raw output format
-n, --noheadings       don't print column headings
-S, --source <string>  the device to mount (by name, maj:min, 
                         LABEL=, UUID=, PARTUUID=, PARTLABEL=)
-o, --output <list>    the output columns to be shown

Available columns:
      ...
      TARGET  mountpoint
      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`mount` knows this.

Example:

```
mount | grep /dev/sdc1
```

Or (likely to be faster):

```
grep '/dev/sdc1' /etc/mtab
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't understood the question then. You can also use `/etc/mtab`.

Comment: Didn't know that, added it :-)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i hoped to find easier way to get path to catalog where my flash is mounted(without using awk/sed), but but it seems there is no such easy way(such as getting link of partition in /dev catalog using it uuid) :)

Answer (score 2):

The kernel's mount table is at `/proc/mounts`.  This is slightly more reliable than `/etc/mtab`, because a system/software error may result in the `mtab` being corrupted or not written to when it should be.

Comment: System error or / beeing mounted read only.

Answer (score 2):

To find the actual device from the UUID, `blkid` may be better than your `readlink` solution, which relies on udev.

```
myuuid="7DCD-9380"
mydev=$(blkid -l -o device -t UUID="$myuuid")
```

To get the mount point for this device, you can use this:

```
grep $mydev /proc/mounts | cut -d' ' -f 2
```

or

```
df -P | grep $mydev | awk '{print $6}'
```

The latter is more portable, because /proc is Linux-only. The `df` solution with the `-P` (POSIX) option should also work on Mac and other Unix systems.

Of course, both would break if your mount point contained spaces. But nobody mounts stuff in "/mnt/evil mount point/", right?

If you fear your predecessor might have done just that, you can use perl instead of awk:

```
df -P | grep $mydev | perl -pe 's/^(\S+\s+){5}//'
```

(the grep could also be handled by perl, but it may be harder to read for some)

The perl regex replaces 5 groups of non-spaces+spaces with nothing, leaving only the rest of line. Which is the mount point including any possible spaces.